# Retrieve data between semicolons that are outside of double quotes

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk

I have the following data in a csv data.
Some columns have data and in the ones there are no data, a semicolon is placed. This cannot change.
The following are an example of the three rows:

```
first;;;;;
;;Second;;;;
;;;"Third;Fourth";;;
;;"Fifth;Sixth";;;
```

I want to get the rows that the number of semicolons does not equal 6.
Moreover, I want to count only the semicolons outside of the double quotes.
So the third row should not be counted as equal to 6.
The fourth, should also be included, because the number of semicolons outside the double quotes is not equal to six.

I use the following code

```
TARGETFILE=data.csv
variable=$(awk -F ';' 'NF != 7' <$TARGETFILE)
```

How can I get the rows that the number of semicolons is not equal to six?

Comment: This isn't really (S)CSV, as the semicolons aren't just *separating* the fields. There should be exactly 5 (unquoted) `;`s in each rows. An empty field is just one with no characters between `;`s (or before the first or after the last).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the expected output, don't just describe it.

Comment: If this is really CSV, you also have to be aware that a field also can contain a valid double quote as content. This would then be escaped by a backslash, if I remember correctly (i.e. `;;\";;;;`).  Another point to consider (which would rule out `awk` as a tool) is that a CSV field can contain a newline character. This would then be between double quotes. I think you better to use a CSV parser.  Of course you can also write one from scratch (and donate it to the community), but why re-inventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '{x=$0; gsub(/"[^"]*"/,"",x)} gsub(/;/,"",x) != 6' file
first;;;;;
;;"Fifth;Sixth";;;
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -F';' '{x=$0; gsub(/"[^"]*"/,"")} NF != 7{print x}' file
first;;;;;
;;"Fifth;Sixth";;;
```

Answer (score 2):

This one-liner should do the trick if you have `GNU awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FPAT = "\"[^\"]*\"|[^;]*" } NF != 7' file
```

Alternatively, you can use this `sed` solution:

```
sed 'h; s/"[^"]*"//g; s/[^;]//g; /^;;;;;;$/d; x' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the rows with six delimeter (non-data) semicolons, `grep` can kind of handle that.

```
$: cat tst
;;;;;;
bad;;;;;
good;;;;;;
;;;;;;;bad
"is;ok";;;;;;
;;good;;;;
;;;;;;"is;ok"
;this;"not;ok";;;
;;;;;;fine
"not;ok";;;
;;"nope;again";;;
;;;;;;;;;"not;ok"

$: grep -En '^(("[^"]*"|[^;"]*)*;("[^"]*"|[^;"]*)*){6}$' tst
1:;;;;;;
3:good;;;;;;
5:"is;ok";;;;;;
6:;;good;;;;
7:;;;;;;"is;ok"
9:;;;;;;fine

$: grep -Env '^(("[^"]*"|[^;"]*)*;("[^"]*"|[^;"]*)*){6}$' tst
2:bad;;;;;
4:;;;;;;;bad
8:;this;"not;ok";;;
10:"not;ok";;;
11:;;"nope;again";;;
12:;;;;;;;;;"not;ok"
```

Even gives you the line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

borrowing Paul's example :

```
 echo '
 ;;;;;;
 bad;;;;;
 good;;;;;;
 ;;;;;;;bad
 "is;ok";;;;;;
 ;;good;;;;
 ;;;;;;"is;ok"
 ;this;"not;ok";;;
 ;;;;;;fine
 "not;ok";;;
 ;;"nope;again";;;
 ;;;;;;;;;"not;ok"' | gcat -n |
```

> ```
> awk -F';?"[^"]*";?|;' NF==7
> ```

```
 1  ;;;;;;
 3  good;;;;;;
 5  "is;ok";;;;;;
 6  ;;good;;;;
 7  ;;;;;;"is;ok"
 9  ;;;;;;fine
```

but for original test samples, has to modify it slightly

(`NF-7` achieves the same effect as `'NF != 7'` without having to shell quote it)

```
 echo '
 first;;;;;
 ;;Second;;;;
 ;;;"Third;Fourth";;;
 ;;"Fifth;Sixth";;;' |
```

> ```
> awk -F';?"[^"]*"|;' NF-7
> ```

```
 first;;;;;
 ;;"Fifth;Sixth";;;
```

Answer (score 0):

CSV format is a lot more complicated than it first appears. For example, I think the way to have a double quote in a string is to have two of them: "". I question if the above solutions handle that, but don't have the energy to analyse them now. I would suggest that the problem to do properly is tough enough that you really need a dedicated program that handles all the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Reusing Pauls file:

```
cat file
;;;;;;
bad;;;;;
good;;;;;;
;;;;;;;bad
"is;ok";;;;;;
;;good;;;;
;;;;;;"is;ok"
;this;"not;ok";;;
;;;;;;fine
"not;ok";;;
;;"nope;again";;;
;;;;;;;;;"not;ok"
```

You can use Ruby to count fields:

```
ruby -r csv -e '$<.each{|line| 
    len=CSV.parse(line, col_sep:";").flatten.length
    puts "#{sprintf("%2s",$.)}: \"#{line.chomp}\" => #{len} fields" 
}' file
```

Prints:

```
 1: ";;;;;;" => 7 fields
 2: "bad;;;;;" => 6 fields
 3: "good;;;;;;" => 7 fields
 4: ";;;;;;;bad" => 8 fields
 5: ""is;ok";;;;;;" => 7 fields
 6: ";;good;;;;" => 7 fields
 7: ";;;;;;"is;ok"" => 7 fields
 8: ";this;"not;ok";;;" => 6 fields
 9: ";;;;;;fine" => 7 fields
10: ""not;ok";;;" => 4 fields
11: ";;"nope;again";;;" => 6 fields
12: ";;;;;;;;;"not;ok"" => 10 fields
```

If you want to filter for those lines that DO have 7 fields:

```
ruby -r csv -e '$<.each{|line| 
    len=CSV.parse(line, col_sep:";").flatten.length
    if len==7 then puts line end
}' file
```

Prints:

```
;;;;;;
good;;;;;;
"is;ok";;;;;;
;;good;;;;
;;;;;;"is;ok"
;;;;;;fine
```

Note: Counting data fields is off by one compared to counting field separators:

```
1;2;3;4;"five; with sep";6 # six fields, five field separators...
```